# laravel-apidoc-generator + dingo api error "The token could not be parsed from the request"

Tags: laravel, dingo-api

Trying to generate API documentation via `laravel-apidoc-generator`, and get the following error:

[image: error]

I tried to use `actAsUserId` and header options and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and still have, but you can try to send authorization token via headers, and if that doesn't work, try to send the token as Query String Parameter. Neither of those work for me...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Notflip Don't know whether the problem even exists now. No I have never found a solution for this

Comment: It's solved (for me), So the Refresh route in Dingo expects a 'token' parameter in the POST request data, I was passing it as an Authorization: Bearer header.